# Undefined reference to class member function when using more than 1 source file

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm trying to learn how to seperate header and implementation files but it is not working even though i tried to keep it as simple as possible

## header file

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

struct Foo{
    void bar();
};

#endif
```

## implementation file

```
 // foo.cpp
 #include "foo.h"
 #include <iostream>

 void Foo::bar(){
     std::cout << "test";
 }
```

## main file

```
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar();
}
```

when i try to compile this, it throws an error

> test.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `Foo::bar()'

Comment: How did you compile it?

Comment: You probably don't link (or otherwise build) with both object (source) files.

Comment: how do i link both?

Comment: Do NOT include cpp files in an `#include` statement.

Comment: BTW, I deleted the answer part from the question. The Q&A format of StackOverflow should not have the answer in the question part.

Comment: Oh sorry, i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compile multiple files, you would add both .cpp files to your project under the same target. Then your DEV C++ IDE will automatically add both files to the build and link them together.

On the completely, different note, Please avoid using DEV C++, it is very very old and hasn't seen updates in years. I'd recommend CodeBlocks instead.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us how you're compiling your code, but you need to compile `foo.cpp` in addition to `test.cpp`. If you're using GCC, the command is:

```
g++ test.cpp foo.cpp -o test
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `void` in the definition of `bar` (in implentation file).
It should be `void Foo::bar() {...`.

Comment: Yes, looks like i forget that. Thanks.